# infopath formatting condition not working

Tags: infopath, formatting

I have these 2 button:

[image]

When amount is more than 1,000,000, I want to hide button approved and show button approved & forward to gceo.

When amount is less than or equal 1,000,000, I want to show button approved and hide button approved & forward to gceo.

[image]

I have set condition as per above for approved button.

[image]

and above for approved & forward to gceo, but when the amount for budgeted is 1,000,001 both button disappear.

I have tried multiple ways but still not correct! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

@moon:

First, the “Approved & Forward to GCEO” button logic, should be:

- ***Rule #1 to Hide the “Approved & Forward to GCEO” button:***

  Budgeted CER cost is blank **and** Unbudgeted CER cost is blank
- ***Rule #2 to Hide the “Approved & Forward to GCEO” button:***

  Budgeted CER cost >$1000000 **and** Unbudgeted CER cost > $1000000
- ***Rule to Display the “Approved & Forward to GCEO” button:***

  Budgeted CER cost >= $1000000 **or** Unbudgeted CER cost >= $1000000

Second, the logic for the “Approved” button, should be:

- ***Rule #1 to Hide the “Approved” button:***

  Budgeted CER cost is blank **and** Unbudgeted CER cost is blank
- ***Rule #2 to Hide the “Approved” button:***

  Budgeted CER cost < $1000000 **or** Unbudgeted CER cost < $1000000
- ***Rule to Display the “Approved” button:***

  Budgeted CER cost <= $1000001 **or** Unbudgeted CER cost <= $1000001

To summarize:
Each button should have 3 rules.  One for if the both fields ‘Budgeted CER’ and ‘Unbudgeted CER’ are *blank*.
The second rule negates the condition for the other’s display, ensuring that the button does not display when the other button does display.
Finally, apply the third condition, affirmatively, that the button *should* display - which is the negation of that button’s second logic rule.
***Apply the rules in the order as they are outlined above!***

**plz up-vote if this answer helped you.**

Comment: @A.kA. Fritz i have tried changing my first condition to and. But when the amount for budgeted is 1,000,001, it shows approved button instead of approved & forward to gceo button.

Comment: @A.kA. Fritz and when the amount for unbudgeted us 1,000,001. both button appears

Comment: @moon:  change the second condition’s logic to be greater than (not greater than or equal to) for BOTH evaluation steps.  Keep the ‘or’.

Comment: Wait, are you applying BOTH sets of logic to BOTH The ‘Approve’ button and the ‘Approved & forward to GCEO’?

Comment: No. the first condition is for 'Approved' and the second set is for 'Approved & forward to GCEO'

Comment: Fritz if i change both to be greater than, when amount for budgeted/unbudgeted equal to 1,000,000 both button appear. when amount for budgeted/unbudgeted greater than 1,000,000 both button dissappear.

Comment: @moon check out my revised answer

Comment: Fritz it is still not working.                                                                            Budgeted CER Cost = 1,000,000, no button appear (approved button should appear);;;Unbudgeted CER Cost =1,000,000, approved button appear (correct).              Budgeted CER cost>1,000,000, no button appear (approved & forward to gceo should appear);;;;;;Unbudgeted CER Cost >1,000,000,approved button appear(approved & forward to gceo should appear)

Comment: I updated the logic one last time after your last comment

Comment: Are there any other items in the form that could possibly effect the presence of either button?

Comment: i also have different view that have same button with formatting condition with lower value, but that button appear just fine according to value with.